# How to initialize instance with dynamic base class

Tags: python-3.x

Environment: python3

I'd like to have some generic object with my custom methods and attributes, so I've created a function that internally creates a class and instance from the class from given base class like the following.

But I am not sure how to initialize the instance with the given value. I would appreciate if you have any ideas?

```
def get_object_with_uuid(value):
    base = type(value)

    class ObjectAndUUID(base):
        def __init__(self):
            self.uuid = "dummy"
            super().__init__()

    return ObjectAndUUID()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = get_object_with_uuid([4,5,6])
    b = get_object_with_uuid((7,8,9))
    c = get_object_with_uuid(10)
    d = get_object_with_uuid("some_string")

    a.append(7)
    print(a)      # '[7]' -> I want this to be [4,5,6,7]
    print(a.uuid) # 'dummy' -> this is expected

    print(b)      # '()' -> I want this to be (7,8,9)
    print(b.uuid) # 'dummy' -> this is expected

    print(c)  # '0' -> I want this to be 10
    print(c.uuid)  # 'dummy' -> this is expected

    print(d)  # '' -> I want this to be 'some_string'
    print(d.uuid)  # 'dummy' -> this is expected
    # and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, Python does not have a generic type of syntax, and based on the current view of the code, there is no need to inherit `str`, `list` or `dict` in `ObkjectAndUUID`. I keep it for consistency only.

Passing arguments to the instance is done via `__init__`. Note that one of the arguments of init is `self`, so there is no need to create it.

```
def get_object_with_uuid(value):
    base = type(value)

    class ObjectAndUUID(base):
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.uuid = "dummy"
            self.val = val

    return ObjectAndUUID(value)
```

Comment: I'd like to preserve the behavior(methods) of the base class. Added a.append in the original question for example.

Comment: I see. Do you consider rewriting `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` for your class? This way, you can apply all methods and attributes to `self.val` except related to UUID.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up rewriting attributes of ``__getattr__``, ``__setattr__``, ``__len__``, ``__str__`` etc. I thought this rewriting was a bit redundant, but since this is a new class, I come to think this is the simplest and highest readability solution. Thanks!